# google chrome only bug

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I have encountered a problem on my website, which I am unable to solve. Here's the [link:](http://www.juxcore.com/x/bmw/html5/modifications.php) . As you can see, there occurs a problem when I try to float:right the picture on the right of "EDIT" and it moves down. The thing is, that this happenes just in Google Chrome, in Firefox or IE it works fine.. I would appreciate any advise 
any mistakes detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 .admineditright{
 width:70px;
 }
```

The current width of this div is 65px, which is not enough, set a higher value like 70px and it will works.

Comment: Good answer. If you have a container div that has a set width, you need to make sure you calculate the width left from children for layout purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the float off the image and moving it to the EDIT?

when I applied `float left;` to the edit it worked. I also applied a small top margin to get the edit to be centered with the image.

Also, note that the bug also existed in chromium. Which is not too surprising considering the relation to chrome and chromium, but sometimes I encounter bugs in chromium that are not found it chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this class:

```
.mod_edits1 {
   float: left;
   margin-top:7px
}
```